# Error in streaming-analytic service in Bluemix

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, message-hub

I followed this tutorial to use the streaming-analytic service in Bluemix to interface with message-hub:  https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/16/streaming-analytics-message-hub-2/?cm_mc_uid=45284031179414585919178&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1464112496

I am getting an error:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException:
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule
>   class: com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubLoginModule

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the error, it seems that you are missing following class: `com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubLoginModule`.

Check this step from tutorial:

> First add the following jars to the opt/downloaded directory of the
>   messaging toolkit.
>
> - jackson-core-2.5.4.jar
> - messagehub.login-1.0.0.jar

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSCRJU_4.1.0/com.ibm.streams.dev.doc/doc/applicationbundle.html) you can check if `messagehub.login-1.0.0.jar` is included in your .sab file:

> To help application and toolkit developers understand which files are
>   included in an application bundle file, you can use the spl-app-info
>   command. For example, the following command lists the toolkits
>   included in the bundle, and the files within those toolkits that are
>   included in the bundle.
>
> `spl-app-info output/MyApp.sab --files`

If it is missing, add it in `/lib` folder.